# How to 'clear' an array of strings?

Tags: c, pointers, arrays

After the initialisation in `main(void)`:

```
char *params[MAXPARAMS] = {NULL};
```

`params` is passed to different functions.

How can I 'reset' the array just as it was during initialisation (after some other functions stored strings in it)?

---

Edit: `params` is used as a parameter list, so it might not be fully populated after certain operations. By 'reset' I meant: I want no string values left inside the array, like how you `clear` a string array in *Java*, but keeping the same array size.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You'll have to keep track of the number of data inside the array using some other variable, which you could set to zero to indicate a reset.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want to achieve: are you content with just clearing the pointers? Do you want to track and "reset" the strings themselves? How would you clear those strings, and is their memory management your responsibility?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the memory allocation is done proerly and it is not freed, I think you need to check the `memset()` function, if you are targeting the values held the array. Please check the man page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset).

Otherwise, if you want to be in the same position as the time of initialization, you can `free()` the allocated memory and again set the variable as `NULL`.

Please clarify what do you mean by `reset`. We'll be able to help out in a batter way then.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is this,

```
for(i=0;i<MAXPARAMS;i++)
    memset(params[i],'\0',strlen(params[i]));
```

keeping the length of each string intact.

Answer (score 0):

If `params` has allocated strings, first free the allocations

```
for (size_t i=0; i<MAXPARAMS; i++) free(params[i]);
```

To get everything back to `NULL`

```
for (size_t i=0; i<MAXPARAMS; i++) params[i] = NULL;
// or 
memset(params, 0, sizeof params);
```

Suggest combining:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<MAXPARAMS; i++) { 
  free(params[i]);
  params[i] = NULL;
}
```